# Jest Compared values have no visual difference. when testing arrays

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I need to test an array returned from refExp using jest.

I am receiving this error:

`Compared values have no visual difference`

Currently I have a workaround and I am using JSON.stringify() within `expect` and `toEqual`, definitely sounds like a hack and I would like to know if I can fix it without it.

Any ideas is appreciated.

Demo:
https://repl.it/repls/VictoriousCapitalProfile

```
const REG_EXP_CHECKBOX = /\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$([^$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)*$)?/
describe('regExp', () => {
  it('should match REG_EXP_CHECKBOX', () => {
    expect('- [ ] $$id=uniq_id$$'.match(REG_EXP_CHECKBOX)).toEqual(
      ['$$id=uniq_id$$', 'uniq_id', undefined, undefined],
    )

    expect(['a', undefined]).toEqual(['a', undefined]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) function that can create shallow-copied Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

The code would look like this ([demo](https://repl.it/repls/CostlyMatureDeskscan)):

```
const REG_EXP_CHECKBOX = /\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$([^$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)*$)?/
describe('regExp', () => {
  it('should match REG_EXP_CHECKBOX', () => {
    expect(Array.from('- [ ] $$id=uniq_id$$'.match(REG_EXP_CHECKBOX) || [])).toEqual(
      ['$$id=uniq_id$$', 'uniq_id', undefined, undefined],
    )
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome! What I was looking for!

Comment: Please note the `...|| []` that can make TS compiler happy if you happen to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Compare arrays is not so simple, because the 2 arrays are not equals, are different objects, with a different instance. So, you have 2 not equal arrays without any visual difference.

What you can do is split your response, and verify for each value, like this:

```
const add = require('./add');
const REG_EXP_CHECKBOX = /\$\$id=(\w+)(?:&amp;description=(\w+))?\$\$([^$]*(?:\$(?!\$)[^$]*)*$)?/
describe('add', () => {
  it('should add two numbers', () => {
    const response = '- [ ] $$id=uniq_id$$'.match(REG_EXP_CHECKBOX);
    expect(response [0]).toEqual('$$id=uniq_id$$');
    expect(response [1]).toEqual('uniq_id');
    expect(response [2]).toBeUndefined();
    expect(response [3]).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

Here you're testing the response, and the string and undefined's will assert correctly.